# Subclass Template error (C++): "error: 'root' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

I'm working on a sub class called "BinarySearchTree" that inherits from its super class "BinaryTree"

BinaryTree.h

```
template <class T>
class BinaryTree 
{

 public:
  BinaryTree() { root = NULL; }

 protected:
  BTNode<T> *root;  // Root node (NULL if the tree is empty)
};
```

BinarySearchTree.h

```
template <class T>
class BinarySearchTree : public BinaryTree<T> 
{
 public:
  BinarySearchTree();  // call super's

  bool insert( const T& elem );
  bool insertHelper(BTNode<T> *&, T );
};

template<class T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree() :  BinaryTree<T>()
{
    root = NULL; // <---- error: In constructor 'BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree()' 
                             //: BinarySearchTree.h:85: error: ‘root’ was not declared in this scope
};
```

I know it has to do with the root not being recognized in scope, but how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
BinaryTree<T>::root = NULL;
```

See here for an explanation:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/nondependent-name-lookup-members.html

Comment: just a follow up question, How come I need to scope it like that?